# Preference Screen and nav & status bar translucent

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, preferenceactivity

I'm using System Bar Tint to make my status and navigation bars translucent and with the color i want. The github: https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint

It's working perfectly! I hace one tiny problem, when the phone turns into landscape or portrait mode.
Because of the translucent status and nav, I have to get the layout and add a margin-top when im in portrait mode for example, simulating this way the space the status bar has.

But my problem comes in PreferenceScreen activity. I use:

```
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
```

to create my preferences screen. And i cannot get the way to change the layoutParams.

Does anyone have a solution for this??

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A1. Use Theme.
[How to apply theme to PreferenceScreen elements of a PreferenceCategory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10228482/how-to-apply-theme-to-preferencescreen-elements-of-a-preferencecategory)

---

A2.

```
ListView listView = getListView();
```

and set layoutParams to listView.

PreferenceActivity is a subclass of ListActivity.